# Get List Of LE devices within range in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

What I need is to get a list of every devices in my range so I can call a certain method on them one after another.

What I have tried so far is to use the startDiscovery() method of the BluetoothAdapter and while it returns a list of devices it takes about 12 seconds to complete which is a lot for my task to complete.

I also managed to user the LeScanCallback succesfully every 2-3 seconds and I do discover devices, but on every scan it returns only one device at a time.
I'm trying to search for Beacons so this type of method could return every call a single other device that uses BlutoothLE when it's found ,while not returning my Beacon's info at all.

So, is there a way to discover a list of all devices in a range without waiting for the startDiscovery() to finish after 12 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. startDiscovery is intended for bluetooth classic devices, not Bluetooth LE.
2. Android does not contain any APIs specific to parsing beacons, only for dealing with raw Bluetooth LE devices.

You can use the free and open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) add-on to detect and parse beacons.  It does not have a 12 second delay and wraps the LeScanCallback method and combines the results so you can get callbacks every second like:

```
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
            Log.i(TAG, "I see a beacon:"+beacon+" that is "+beacon.getDistance()+" meters away.");     
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can I use this library without having to extend Application ? And can I do my Scanning in a Service ?

Comment: Yes to both questions!  You can see an example of using the library to scan for beacons inside an Activity in the Ranging Example Code here: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html.  You can also use the library inside a service.  The same example code mentioned before will work, just put it inside a Service instead of inside an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [startScan(ScanCallback)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan%28android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback%29) api of BluetoothLeScanner to start scanning, this has support on Android 21(5.0).

Also look below question, it has sample code you can use to start/stop Le Scanning.

[How to restart BluetoothLeScanner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28898861/519718)